# How do I implement a reset button for my GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am an AP Computer Science student and I need help with my assignment for the class. My assignment is to create a simple GUI or game using Eclipse. I made a simple player vs. player tic-tac-toe game, but I do not know how to create a "reset" button for my GUI. I tried multiple times, but I can't get it to work or show up in my GUI. I would appreciate some pointers on how to implement a functional reset button, so I would not have exit out of my GUI multiple times to start playing again. Here is the code I have written so far.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToeGUI implements ActionListener 
{
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
    JButton[] button;
    JButton reset = new JButton("Reset"); 
    String letter = "";
    public int count = 0;
    public boolean win = false;

    public TicTacToeGUI()
    {
        button = new JButton[9];
        window.setSize(300,300);
        window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
        JButton dummy = new JButton("");
        Font font = dummy.getFont();
        Font bigFont = font.deriveFont(font.getSize2D() * 5.0f);
        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            button[i] = new JButton("");
            button[i].setFont(bigFont);
            button[i].addActionListener(this);
            window.add(button[i]);
        }
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) 
    {
        count++;

        if(count % 2 == 1)
        {
            letter = "X";
        }
        else
        {
            letter = "O";
        }

        Object but = a.getSource();

        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
        {
            if(but == button[i]) 
            {
                button[i].setText(letter);
                button[i].setEnabled(false);
                break;
            }
        }

        if( button[0].getText() == button[1].getText() && button[1].getText() == button[2].getText() && button[0].getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button[3].getText() == button[4].getText() && button[4].getText() == button[5].getText() && button[3].getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button[6].getText() == button[7].getText() && button[7].getText() == button[8].getText() && button[6].getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button[0].getText() == button[3].getText() && button[3].getText() == button[6].getText() && button[0].getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button[1].getText() == button[4].getText() && button[4].getText() == button[7].getText() && button[1].getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button[2].getText() == button[5].getText() && button[5].getText() == button[8].getText() && button[2].getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button[0].getText() == button[4].getText() && button[4].getText() == button[8].getText() && button[0].getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else if(button[2].getText() == button[4].getText() && button[4].getText() == button[6].getText() && button[2].getText() != "")
        {
            win = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            win = false;
        }

        if(win == true)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " WINS!");
        } 
        else if(count == 9 && win == false)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie Game!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new TicTacToeGUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
    window.setLayout(new  BorderLayout());
    JPanel panel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(3, 3)); 
    window.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);  // add panel to window center
    window.add(reset, BorderLayout.SOUTH);   // add reset button to window bottom
```

Of course, you will have to add your 9 buttons to `panel` now, not to `window`.

But why don't you just reset automatically after the user confirmed the dialog at the end of the game?

Answer (score 0):

Reset your board after a tie or win. An example reset method. Otherwise you are going to have to make room on your Frame to hold a button to do this.

```
private void ResetBoard() {
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    button[i].setText("");
    button[i].setEnabled(true);
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

Then use this method when a check is made to see if a player won or the game ends in a tie as below:

```
if(win == true)
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " WINS!");
   ResetBoard();
} 
else if(count == 9 && win == false)
{
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tie Game!");
   ResetBoard();
}
```